# jQuery ajax returns

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a slider with 3 slides - Intro, Question, Submit.

Now I want to make sure that if the question is answered wrong people cannot slide to Submit.

The function to move slide is like this:

```
function changeSlide(slide){

        // In case current slide is question check the answer
        if (jQuery('.modalSteps li.current',base).hasClass('questionStep')){
            checkAnswer(jQuery('input[name="question_id"]',base).val(), jQuery('input[name="answer"]:checked',base).val());
        }

        jQuery('.modalSteps li.current',base).fadeOut('fast',function(){
            jQuery(this).removeClass('current');
            jQuery(slide).fadeIn('fast',function(){
                jQuery(slide).addClass('current');
            });
        });

        // In case the new slide is question, load the question
        if (jQuery(slide).hasClass('questionStep')){
            var country = jQuery('input[name="country"]:checked',base).val();
            loadQuestion(country);
        }
    }
```

Now as you can see on first lines, I am calling function checkAnswer, which takes id of question and id of answer and pass it to the AJAX call.

```
function checkAnswer(question, answer){
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: window.base_url+'ajax/check_answer/'+question+'/'+answer+'/',
            success: function(data){
                if (!data.success){
                    jQuery('.question',base).html(data.message);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

The problem i am having is that I cannot say

```
if(checkAnswer(...)){}
```

Because of Ajax it always returns false or undefined. What I need is something like this:

```
 function changeSlide(slide){

        // In case current slide is question check the answer
        if (jQuery('.modalSteps li.current',base).hasClass('questionStep')){
            if (!checkAnswer(jQuery('input[name="question_id"]',base).val(), jQuery('input[name="answer"]:checked',base).val())){
              return false;
            }
        }
...
```

So it will prevent the slide from moving on.

Now when I'm thinking about it, I will probably have slide like "Wrong answer" so I could just move the slide there, but I would like to see the first solution anyway.

Comment: have you tried making your ajax call synchronous? because you should.  and inside your check answer you should have some sort of return variable that is set inside the success function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set option async of ajax to false to wait for the reply from server. Therefore, the code may be like the below.

```
function checkAnswer(question, answer){
    result = false;
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: window.base_url+'ajax/check_answer/'+question+'/'+answer+'/',
        success: function(data){
            result = data.success
            if (!data.success){
                jQuery('.question',base).html(data.message);
            }
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You see this is exactly what I was talking about. I didn't know you can turn off the async... Thanks for that! going to try it out